# Apache POI Excel Invalid Header Signature only in Junit test

Tags: java, excel, apache, junit

I have a issue with Apache POI when i want created a workbook in my Junit Test. I give this error "Invalid Header Signature" but when i try by the User interface of the app the workbook is correctly created. I don't understand this problem because it's the same file for my unit test and my test via UI (format 
.xls).

An idea for fix this issue ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: any person for help me ?

Comment: Some code would be helpful.